# $new_pass always returns null - password_reset hook

Tags: hooks, actions

I am trying to catch the username and the new password to update it on the backup server. I need to fetch $new_pass but the password always returns null.

```
add_action( 'password_reset', 'remote_password_update' );
function remote_password_update( $user, $new_pass ) {

        $username = $user->user_login; //THIS WORKS PERFECTLY
        $password = $new_pass; //THIS ALWAYS RETURNS NULL

}
```

This is pretty basic and straight forward, so I am not sure what the problem is. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that:

```
add_action( 'password_reset', 'remote_password_update' );
```

is like calling:

```
add_action( 'password_reset', 'remote_password_update', 10, 1 );
```

where 10 is the default priority and 1 is the number of arguments.

You need:

```
add_action( 'password_reset', 'remote_password_update', 10, 2 );
```

with 2 as the number of arguments. Now you should be able to access the  `$new_pass` input variable.